# PHP Replace - Get elements from other php file?

Tags: php, replace

I have this code:

```
<?php
    $test = 'My name is Dan';
    echo str_replace("Dan","Peter", $test);
?>
```

I want the elements Dan and Peter to come from another php file. I want something like:

```
<?php
    $test = 'My name is Dan';
    echo str_replace($elements, $test);
?>
```

And `$elements` would contain `"Dan", "Peter"`, so both elements in the same file.

Bonus question: Is it possible to add something like: if `$elements` in not available/not accessible then don't replace anything?

I am pretty new to php.

Comment: And where is the problem ?

Comment: @Rizier123 How do I add the elements to the second file? I can't get it working whatever I do. I get: Warning: str_replace() expects at least 3 parameters, 2 given

Comment: Then show your current code of both files and where you include them

Comment: if $element var is in an other php file with the same name, you have to include this file before echo.

Comment: it's included but I forgot to put it in the example above. My quesiton: how will the included file look like? Simply "Dan", "Peter" or echo "Dan", "Peter" ??

Comment: include file :   .... $element="Dan", "Peter"; ...

Comment: @10now You can provide an array on both the search and replace side, but you can't combine the search and replace into one array... You'd have to create that yourself... Try reading some documentation... ;)

Comment: you can declare in include file $search='Dan'; $replace='Peter';  so in original file  echo str_replace($search,$replace, $test);

Comment: @luca that's exactly what I just did :). Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I did it myself.
I added two $strings. So now it's like this:

```
echo str_replace("$string1","$string2", $test);
```